# How can you check out the oldest revision of a subfolder in SVN?

Tags: svn, vim

I have a subfolder of an SVN repository checked out. I'd like to script `svn diff -r$OLDESTREVISION > diff && vim diff && rm diff` so I can alias it to something like `difforig`.

`OLDESTREVISION` will be different for every subfolder I want to run this in, so I can't just hardcode it. I could `svn log` and parse the output for the oldest column, but that'll require password entry and more time than I'd like it to take.

`svn help diff` returns

```
  -r [--revision] ARG      : ARG (some commands also take ARG1:ARG2 range)
                             A revision argument can be one of:
                                NUMBER       revision number
                                '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
                                'HEAD'       latest in repository
                                'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
                                'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
                                'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
```

but `svn diff -rBASE` doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to diff the first and latest version of file, you could use something like ag or grep to extract the first revision number and build dynamically your diffs for a series of files:

```
svn diff -"$(svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1 ./gnu_regex/regex.c | ag -o 'r[0-9]+'):HEAD" ./gnu_regex/regex.c
```